# Recording high frequency time-series data with influxdb

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python, influxdb-2

I want to record data every 10 milliseconds. Here is the sample code:

```
with InfluxDBClient(url=url, token=token, org=org, enable_gzip=True) as client:
    with client.write_api(
        write_options=WriteOptions(
            batch_size=100, flush_interval=500, jitter_interval=0
        )
    ) as write_client:

        while True:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            val = np.random.randint(10)
            print(val)
            write_client.write(
                bucket,
                org,
                {
                    "measurement": "my_measurement",
                    "fields": {"my_value": int(val)},
                },
            )
            write_client.flush()
```

However, the above does not record with a required frequency. Also, it is confusing for me how the batching will be handled in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `time` for the data point, otherwise it will be assigned server time *when* it is received by the server. Batching won't affect it even more then.